# handling updating state when value comes in undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-hooks

I am having trouble handling cases where the users phone number comes in undefined. I attempted to make the state conditional which I believe is bad practice so now I am using the `useEffect` hook to update the state on page load but now my `onChange` function in the field is not working for updating the state. Here's my code:

```
const EditableSection = ({
  profile,
  patientSex,
  editingProfile,
  setEditingProfile,
  userID,
  setProfile,
}) => {
const [PCPAreaCode, setPCPAreaCode] = useState();
  const [PCPThreeDigit, setPCPThreeDigit] = useState();
  const [PCPFourDigit, setPCPFourDigit] = useState();

 useEffect(()=> {
    if (!profile.medicalProfile.primaryCareProvider.fax){
      setPCPAreaCode("")
      setPCPThreeDigit("")
      setPCPFourDigit("")
    }else{
      setPCPAreaCode(profile.medicalProfile.primaryCareProvider.fax.split(" ")[0]);
      setPCPThreeDigit(profile.medicalProfile.primaryCareProvider.fax.split(" ")[1].split("-")[0]);
      setPCPFourDigit(profile.medicalProfile.primaryCareProvider.fax.split("-")[1]);
    }
   
  });

const submitData = async () => {
    if (!validProps()) {
      return;
    }
    let res = await api.UserRecords.update(userID, { 
      PCPhysician: {
        fax: `${PCPAreaCode} ${PCPThreeDigit}-${PCPFourDigit}`,
        name: PCPName
      }
    });


if (editingProfile) {
    return (
<FormGroup>
   <div className={styles.profileBlock}>
            <div className="d-flex">
              <Input
                type="text"
                maxLength="3"
                defaultValue={PCPAreaCode.replace(/\(|\)/g, "")}
                onChange={(e) => setPCPAreaCode(e.target.value)}
                className={PCPFaxError ? styles.inputError : styles.inputField}
                style={{ width: "4rem" }}
              />
              <Input
                type="text"
                maxLength="3"
                defaultValue={PCPThreeDigit}
                onChange={(e) => setPCPThreeDigit(e.target.value)}
                className={PCPFaxError ? styles.inputError : styles.inputField}
                style={{ width: "4rem" }}
              />
              <Input
                type="text"
                maxLength="4"
                defaultValue={PCPFourDigit}
                onChange={(e) => setPCPFourDigit(e.target.value)}
                className={PCPFaxError ? styles.inputError : styles.inputField}
                style={{ width: "4rem" }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
</FormGroup>

)
  }

  return (
<>
 <div className={styles.profileBlock}>
            <h2>Primary Care Provider</h2>
            <p>
              {PCPName || "Not provided"}, Fax: {`${PCPAreaCode} ${PCPThreeDigit}-${PCPFourDigit}` || "Not provided"}
            </p>
        </div> 
    </>
```

So right now when I add a value in these input fields It doesnt update and im wondering if theres something im obviously doing wrong here?

Comment: I think the problem is that your `useEffect` function is called on every single rerender (which itself causes on infinite loop). You can give it a second argument, of an empty array if you only want it to run on the initial render - or of `[profile.medicalProfile.primaryCareProvider.fax]` if you only want it to run when that value changes.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I see now how its an infinite loop in my useEffect function. When you say give it a second argument of an empty array do you mean inside my if statement?

Comment: should be something like this: - `useEffect(() => {}, [])` or `useEffect(() => {}, [profile.medicalProfile.primaryCareProvider.fax])`. Second argument in your `useEffect` is `array` or `[]`

Comment: no, I mean give `useEffect` a second argument. The first argument is a function, which you've given it, but you haven't given it an array as the second argument - this means that the effect will run on every single render. See for example [this](https://flaviocopes.com/react-hook-useeffect/)